# Drag and Drop with animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is more of a theoretical question which I hope is okay!? I want to code my own drag and drop jQuery plugin, but i'm wondering the best way to go about structuring my code and actually doing it.

**Note:** This MAY be opinion orientated as well but I don't mind, I just need suggestions on a good way to go about this and structuring the code etc.

Current plan:

**Item Class:** I want to use Object Orientated Programming here, so was going to store the reference to each draggable item in an instance of a class, which are in turn stored within an array. Then within this class I can do calculations based on that draggable item.

**When to capture mousemove:** To save on computing power incase of other JavaScript intensive scripts I was thinking about only capturing any mouse movements when the mouse is down on an item.

**Actually moving items:** Well, I will just change the items position to fixed/absolute and adjust the top and left values, what happens on release I cover below.

**Moving items out of the way to place selected, and actually dropping an item in a new location:** That's a long bolded one! But yeah, i'm not too sure on how I would go about this! Basically I would have a list of `li's` which I want to re-order, but as I move an item to a new position I want the other items to slide out of the way smoothly, preferably using transforms as to pass the animation over to the GPU.

**Moving items into other stacks:** Some of my `li's` may have `ul's` within then, I need the ability to detect when the draggable item is being attempted to be dropped into another item. If this makes sense! :(

---

Kinda example structure of my items?

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="1">Home</li>
  <li id="2">Showroom
    <ul>
      <li>Stoke</li>
      <li>Macclesfield</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="3">Finance</li>
  <li id="4">Servicing</li>
  <li id="5">About Us</li>
  <li id="6">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

I have sort of started some of the code, however I don't want to do too much if i'm going about it all wrong!

```
/* Global Javascript */
(function($) {
  $.fn.draggable = function() {
    // Establish our default settings
    var settings = $.extend({ }, options);

    class Item {
      constructor(obj) {
        this.elm = obj;
      }

      // Return the items dimentions
      getDimentions() {
        return new array((this.obj).outerWidth(), (this.obj).outerHeight());
      }
    }
    // Store draggable items
    var $items = new Array();
    $(this).each() {
      if ($(this).is('li')) {
        $items[] = new Item($(this));
      }
    }
    console.log($items);


    var $dragObject = null;
    function makeClickable(object) {
      object.onmousedown = function() {
        $dragObject = this;
      }
    }
    function mouseUp(ev) {
      $dragObject = null;
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
$('sortable').draggable();
```

Comment: Have you thought about looking at, say, how jQueryUI does it?

Comment: check out [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/)